# C# substring with separators

Tags: c#, substring

How can I get substring separated with `.` ignoring first separator?

For example `1.2` substring from string `1.2.3.4`

or`123.13` form `123.13.145.1234`?

Comment: How do you tell the difference between the . to split and the . for decimal point?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx  ....as a starting point.

Comment: why do you give downvotes and scary to explain it ot TS?

Comment: please show code you have tried - ant the question can be reopened after it

Comment: Use this regex @"[^\.]+\.[^\.]+(?=\.)"

Comment: seems like input strings are version numbers, then you can try `(new Version("123.13.145.1234")).ToString(2)` - [Demo](http://ideone.com/3kk3V8)

Comment: @Damith: Good point, i have edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20093730/284240) to take that into account.

Answer (score 3):

So you want just the first two parts? Use `String.Split('.')`, `Take(2)` and `String.Join` to concat both:

```
string twoParts = string.Join(".", "123.13.145.1234".Split('.').Take(2));
```

**Edit**: Your input string seems to be a version number, so if you need it's major and minor part parse it to `Version` and use it's appropriate properties:

```
Version v = Version.Parse("123.13.145.1234");
string major = v.Major;  // 123
string minor = v.Minor;  // 13
```

or, if you really want it as string (thanks for your comment @Damith):

```
string majorMinor = v.ToString(2); // 123.13
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `Substring()` function to get part of `String`

Try This:

```
        String str = "1.2.3.4";
        Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(".",str.IndexOf(".")+1)));
        str = "123.13.145.1234";
        Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(".", str.IndexOf(".") + 1)));
```

Output:

```
1.2
123.13
```

Comment: I think, because you don't found second "." index and set it manually.

Comment: ok agree. Some explanation helps

Comment: @VikciaR: Please check my edited answer and let me know if anything is missing?

Comment: Thank you all for giving me a chance to correct my mistake.